# Transformation law for symmetric rank-2 tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

A rank-2 tensor $M_{ij}$ transforms as $M_{ij} \rightarrow O_{ik} O_{jl} M_{kl}$, where $O$ is some element of $SO(n)$.

We can always get a symmetric tensor from $M_{ij}$ through $M_{ij}^s =M_{ij} + M_{ji} $ and equivalently of course an antisymmetric tensor $M_{ij}^a = M_{ij} - M_{ji}$$ .

The transformation law for the symmetric tensor is then

$$ M_{ij}^s = M_{ij} + M_{ji}  \rightarrow O_{ik} O_{jl} M_{kl} + O_{jk} O_{il} M_{kl}, $$

which is thinks means written in matrix notation $OMO^T + (OMO^T)^T = OMO^T + OM^TO^T$. (Transposing switches the position of $O^T$ and $O$ and in addition they get transposed. Thus only $M$ becomes $M^T$ when we transpose the second expression.)

Next, I want to know how the generators $T$ of $SO(n)$ act on $M$. We can write $O=e^{i \epsilon T}$. Then we have, using $T^T = -T$ and $AB-BA \equiv [A,B]$.

$$OMO^T + (OMO^T)^T = e^{i \epsilon T} M e^{-i \epsilon T} + e^{i \epsilon T} M^T e^{-i \epsilon T} $$

We can rewrite the two terms using the series expansion for $e^{i \epsilon T}= 1 + i \epsilon T + \ldots$, neglecting terms $O(\epsilon^2)$.

$$e^{i \epsilon T} M e^{-i \epsilon T} = (1 + i \epsilon T) M (1 - i \epsilon T ) = M + i \epsilon  [T,M]  $$

$$ e^{i \epsilon T} M^T e^{-i \epsilon T} =  (1 + i \epsilon T ) M^T (1 - i \epsilon T ) =M^T + i \epsilon [T,M^T] $$

Therefore

$$e^{i \epsilon T} M e^{-i \epsilon T} + e^{-i \epsilon T} M^T e^{i \epsilon T} =  M + i \epsilon  [T,M] + M^T + i \epsilon [T,M^T] $$
$$ =  M^s +  i \epsilon  [T,M^s] $$

For the transformation behaviour of $M^a$ I get analogous

$$  M^a \rightarrow M^a+ i \epsilon [T,M^a]$$