# How do Lie algebra elements act on symmetric and antisymmetric representations?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

The Lie algebra of a group acts on itself through the commutator $ T_a \in ad$:

$$ T_a \circ T_b = [T_a,T_b] \in ad $$

I assume the same should be true if we have an antisymmetric adjoint, as for example for $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, because [Antisymmetric, Antisymmetric]=Antisymmetric.

The adjoint can be written as tensor product representation of the fundamental and the antifundamental $f \otimes \bar f$ or $f \otimes f$ if $f$ is real. For $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ the adjoint is simply the antisymmetric part of this tensor product. I tried to compute the corresponding transformation laws [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383093/transformation-law-for-symmetric-rank-2-tensors), using this, but failed miserably.

What is the correct transformation law for the symmetric part of the tensor product repreentation $f \otimes f$? A naive guess would be

$$ T_a \circ S = [T_a,S], $$

because [Symmetric,Antisymmetric]=Symmetric.

Comment: If both $V$ and $W$ are representations of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, then their tensor product $V\otimes W$ is also a representation under the action
$$x\cdot(v\otimes w)=(x\cdot v)\otimes w+v\otimes (x\cdot w).$$ I don't know what the term *antisymmetric adjoint* means, but if you have identified it as a submodule of the tensor product of the fundamental rep and its dual, then this formula is automatic. You also get it out of the usual way of interpreting elements of Lie algebra as infinitesimal generators of a Lie group.

Comment: In other words, if the action of $x$ on $V$ is given by matrix $A$, and its action on $W$ is given by matrix $B$ (w.r.t. som bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively), then its action on the tensor product (w.r.t. to the product of the two bases) is given by $A\otimes I+I\otimes B$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your comments. For example, for $\mathfrak{so}(10)$ one has $10 \otimes 10 = 45_a + 1_s+ 55_s$. This means if we decompose the tensor product representation of two times the real fundamental $10$, the antisymmetric part is the adjoint $45_a$. Written as tensor products $45_a= 10 \otimes 10 - 10 \otimes 10$. Equivalently the symmetric part is $54_s+1_s= 10 \otimes 10 + 10 \otimes 10$ (which looks a lot like zero, see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383811/why-arent-all-elements-of-the-45-a-representation-of-so10-zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The action of some generator $T$ on some element of $10$ is simply matrix times vector. Thus $ T \circ 45_a = (T \circ 10 ) \otimes 10 + 10 \otimes  (T \circ 10 )  -  (T \circ 10 )  \otimes 10 - 10 \otimes  (T \circ 10 )  $. My problem is translating this in terms of matrices.

Comment: Ok. 1) use the above formula on the tensor product: $T$ acts as $T\otimes I_{10}-I_{10}\otimes T$. 2) restrict this action to the (stable) 45-dimensional subspace of the antisymmetric part. Probably you want to fix a basis for the antisymmetric part. The one consisting of vectors of the form $e_i\otimes e_j-e_j\otimes e_i, 1\le i<j\le10$, is the most natural choice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot! I think I was now able to solve my problem and wrote an answer myself